# .NET issues with FileStream

Tags: .net, vb.net, file, file-io

I am trying to create a `FileStream` from a file with the following line:

```
Dim fStream As FileStream = New FileStream(destinationPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Read)
```

When I do this, I get an error saying

```
Combining FileMode: Create with FileAccess: Read is invalid.
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Edit: I am trying to read from a file, not create it.

Answer (score 3):

`Read` access does not allow you to make any modifications to a file. Creating a file counts as a modification. You will need to use either `Write` or `ReadWrite` access.

Edit: Of course, there is a second scenario:

If you are trying to read from a file that already exists, do not use `FileMode.Create`. Instead, use `FileMode.Open`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to create (and possibly write to) a file, it would make more sense to use `FileAccess.Write` or maybe `FileAccess.ReadWrite`.

Answer (score 1):

Because `Create` contradicts with `Read`. try `New FileStream(destinationPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite)`

Answer (score 1):

The error message says what is the problem: When you *create* a new file, you are expected to *write* into it, not *read* from it. As you are creating a new file, there is nothing in it to read.

Change the third argument to `FileAccess.Write`.

Answer (score 1):

With [`FileMode.Create`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/System.IO.FileMode.aspx) you're specifying that you want the file at `destinationPath` to be created (or recreated if it already exists), giving you a new, empty file.  With a new file there's no data to be read.  You should pass a [`FileAccess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/4z36sx0f.aspx) value that includes the `Write` flag.

Answer (score 1):

How can you create a file if you can only read it? You need to specify that you also have write access to the file. [MSDN for FileAccess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4z36sx0f) Try:

```
Dim fStream As FileStream = New FileStream(destinationPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite)
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, sorry it wasn't clear, but as mentioned, my intention was to read the file. The correct way to do it was:

```
Dim fStream As FileStream = New FileStream(destinationPath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
```